# CakePHP 3 - association is not defined - even though it appears to be

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I've baked a legacy application using CakePHP 3.7

The database contains 3 tables as follows: `regulations`, `groups`, `filters`. The hierarchy as far as the application goes is:

- Regulations

  - Groups

    - Filters

The table schemas are as follows:

```
mysql> describe regulations;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| label | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.09 sec)

mysql> describe groups;
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| regulation_id | int(4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| label         | varchar(255)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> describe filters;
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(100)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| label    | text                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| group_id | int(4) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So when I baked the application I got the following Table class relationships. All are inside the `initialize()` method:

```
// RegulationsTable.php
$this->hasMany('Groups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'regulation_id'
    ]);

// GroupsTable.php
$this->belongsTo('Regulations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'regulation_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Filters', [
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
    ]);

 // FiltersTable.php
 $this->belongsTo('Groups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

In my mind this seems correct because those are the relationships as far as the schema goes.

However, when I try and do this in a Controller:

```
$regulations = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Regulations');
$data = $regulations->find('all')->contain(['Groups', 'Filters']);
$data = $data->toArray();
debug($data);
```

It's giving an error:

> The Filters association is not defined on Regulations.

Well, obviously. Because the association for that is handled through the Groups (`GroupsTable.php`) model. There is no **direct** relationship between Filters and Regulations; it must go via Groups.

Please can someone advise what is wrong with the baked Models so that this won't produce an error?

For background info: the use case is getting a list of the data (specifically the `label` from each table) in a hierarchical format (Regulations --> Groups --> Filters).

Comment: The models are fine, you're looking for containing nested associations **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain**

Comment: @ndm Thanks. Is that not what I'm doing with `->contain(...)` though?

Comment: No, you're passing the associations on the same level, you need to define them in a nested fashion as shown in the examples 2 to 4.