# Paginate and search associated query with dynamic AJAX loading in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am working on an application in CakePHP 3.7.

We have 3 database tables with the following hierarchy. These tables are associated correctly according to the Table classes:

- `regulations`

  - `groups`

    - `filters`

(The associations are shown in a previous question: [CakePHP 3 - association is not defined - even though it appears to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563186/cakephp-3-association-is-not-defined-even-though-it-appears-to-be))

I can get all of the data from all three tables as follows:

```
$regulations = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Regulations');
$data = $regulations->find('all', ['contain' => ['Groups' => ['Filters']]]);
$data = $data->toArray();
```

The `filters` table contains >1300 records. I'm therefore trying to build a feature which loads the data progressively via AJAX calls as the user scrolls down the page similar to what's described here: https://makitweb.com/load-content-on-page-scroll-with-jquery-and-ajax/

The problem is that I need to be able to count the total number of rows returned. However, the data for this exists in 3 tables.

If I do `debug($data->count());` it will output 8 because there are 8 rows in the `regulations` table. Ideally I need a count of the rows it's returning in the `filters` table (~1300 rows) which is where most of the data exists in terms of the initial load.

The problem is further complicated because this feature allows a user to perform a search. It might be the case that a given search term exists in all 3 tables, 1 - 2 of the tables, or not at all. I don't know whether the correct way to do this is to try and count the rows returned in each table, or the rows overall?

I've read [How to paginate associated records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901181/how-to-paginate-associated-records) and [Filtering By Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data) in the Cake docs.

### Additional information

The issue seems to come down to how to write a query using the ORM syntax Cake provides. The following (plain MySQL) query will actually do what I want. Assuming the user has searched for "Asbestos":

```
SELECT
regulations.label AS regulations_label,
groups.label AS groups_label,
filters.label AS filters_label
FROM
groups
JOIN regulations
ON groups.regulation_id = regulations.id 
JOIN filters
ON filters.group_id = groups.id
WHERE regulations.label LIKE '%Asbestos%'
OR groups.label LIKE '%Asbestos%'
OR filters.label LIKE '%Asbestos%'
ORDER BY
regulations.id ASC,
groups_label ASC,
filters_label ASC
LIMIT 0,50
```

Let's say there are 203 rows returned. The `LIMIT` condition means I am getting the first 50. Some js on the frontend (which isn't really relevant in terms of how it works) will make an ajax call as the user scrolls to the bottom of the page to re-run this query with a different limit (e.g. `LIMIT 51, 100` for the next set of results).

The problem seems to be two fold:

1. If I write the query using Cake's ORM syntax the output is a nested array. Conversely if I write it in plain SQL it's returning a table which has just 3 columns with the labels that I need to display. This structure is much easier to work with in terms of outputting the required data on the page.
2. The second - and perhaps *more important issue* - is that I can't see how you could write the `LIMIT` condition in the ORM syntax to make this work due to the nested structure described in 1. If I added `$data->limit(50)` for example, it only imposes this limit on the `regulations` table. So essentially the search works for any associated data on the first 50 rows in `regulations`. As opposed to the `LIMIT` condition I've written in MySQL which would take into consideration the entire result set which includes the columns from all 3 tables.

To further elaborate point 2, assume the tables contain the following numbers of rows:

- `regulations`: 150
- `groups`: 1000
- `filters`: 5000

If I use `$data->limit(50)` it would only apply to 50 rows in the `regulations` table. I need to apply the `LIMIT` the result set after searching all rows in all 3 tables for a given term.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem... it sounds like you could simply count on the `filters` table in a separate query?

Comment: @ndm thanks. The search feature means that the user could search for records that exist in any 3 tables. So they could end up with a record that's in the `groups` table but has no corresponding rows in the `filters` table. The count of the total rows returned (which is really the sum of all 3 levels: `regulations`, `groups`, `filters`) would be required for the ajax loader to do it's work.

Comment: You would have to apply the same search conditions there too, but it's hard to give further advice on that, without knowing how exactly you are implementing the search query, and the pagination.

Comment: @ndm I've started a bounty as I'm having a hard time with this. Some additional information is on the question now. The real struggle is the second point with how to apply the `LIMIT` condition such that it works for all 3 tables simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating that query using the query builder is pretty simple, if you want joins for non-1:1 associations, then use the `*JoinWith()` methods instead of `contain()`, in this case `innerJoinWith()`, something like:

```
$query = $GroupsTable
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'regulations_label' => 'Regulations.label',
        'groups_label' => 'Groups.label',
        'filters_label' => 'Filters.label',
    ])
    ->innerJoinWith('Regulations')
    ->innerJoinWith('Filters')
    ->where([
        'OR' => [
            'Regulations.label LIKE' => '%Asbestos%',
            'Groups.label LIKE' => '%Asbestos%',
            'Filters.label LIKE' => '%Asbestos%',
        ],
    ])
    ->order([
        'Regulations.id' => 'ASC',
        'Groups.label' => 'ASC',
        'Filters.label' => 'ASC',
    ]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using innerJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)**